# How to create the slideshow as the background slideshow using drupal 7?

Tags: theming, views, javascript

We are currently developing a single page responsive site in drupal 7.In our home page we tried implementing slideshow through view slideshow module (drupal 7). The slideshow is working perfectly fine. I want to know how to create a background slideshow using views slideshow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Backstretch](https://drupal.org/project/backstretch) module and see the [demo](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) in action(In dropdown select "Using Backstrech as slideshow") Even though it is in dev stage but it works well in my production without issue.

> This module provides a field formatter and Context integration for
>   jQuery Backstretch - A simple jQuery plugin that allows you to add a
>   dynamically-resized, slideshow-capable background image to any page or
>   element.

Comment: Thank you..went through your suggested module and watched the demo. In action after selecting dropdown "using backstretch as slideshow" saw a raw code. can you suggest where to add that ? will it be adapting to the responsive theme?

Comment: @NijiMonachan create separate content type and add image field and in manage display set the format as backstrech and set that page as front page or if you already created the front page add the image field to that content type and set the format as backstrech. Ya it is completely responsive!!!!

Comment: Thank you Bala...can you suggest how to make it for one page,that is only the home page and should not reflect other pages?

Comment: @NijiMonachan do you have homepage already ?

Comment: Yes we have one ,the issue is we set the way as you suggested and it worked fine,but the slideshow is turning up for other pages also.we want to add slideshow only for the homepage as it is a professional site .we tried our maximum,but not finding any solution..after solving one issue we get poked with other..now the slider and responsive nature is not working!!

Comment: @NijiMonachan I suggest you to create separate content type for home page, which will show only to front page.

Comment: Thanx !!its working perfectly fine now...

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [Vegas Background jQuery Plugin](https://drupal.org/project/vegas) module.

> Vegas is a jQuery plugin to add beautiful fullscreen backgrounds and slideshows to your webpages.

Try out the module [demo](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/).

Comment: Above is a module and you can use it with out worrying about your theme... You can use above module with your already existing theme..

Comment: Ok...but after installing the jquery plugin for our responsive site,the slideshow seems not to be responsive!! can you suggest me with a responsive one !

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this vegas module. Its not only Full Screen but its also Responsive. Most importantly very easy.

Answer (score -1):

The [Photo](https://www.drupal.org/project/photo) module is great but still alpha stage. Details from its project page:

> Photo is a photography and multimedia theme with a full screen slideshow. Showcase your important work, imagination with full screen photo slider. Photo is Drupal theme for photographic professionals, photo artist, amateur photographers to create photo gallery, portfolio with photos, video blogs. It is also useful for architecture, travel sites, hotels, restaurants, sculpture artist and for any purpose who want to emphasis on photos for the website.

Otherwise Write your own JS or add JS plugin to get this effect. With Jquery, anything is possible.

Comment: Above is a theme .. It's not a module...

Comment: Thank you ,for your warm response.Actually we implemented a theme for single page website,so after configuring vegas background plugin ,will it change the existing theme's configuration?  Is there any Jquery plugin or any other drupal plugin apart from a theme?